# Find the closest point in geometry from other point to reform or sort the unordered coordinates in geometry in Python

Tags: python, coordinates, computational-geometry, knn, nearest-neighbor

I am working on the task in which I have to find the nearest (closest) point from other point. The reason behind this problem is I want to reform (sort) the coordinate number in my geometry such a way that, every consecuttive nodes placed next to each other.

For that, I started to check the first point which is nearest to my origin (0, 0).
I have list of coordinates as below,

```
X = [2, 4, 4, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 1, 3, 4, 3, 1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 2, 0]
Y = [3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]

len(X2_coordinate)
19
```

and Origin is,

```
origin_x = 0
origin_y = 0
```

How can find the nearest point from origin??

I have written below code to find the distance between origin to all other points (mentioned in X and Y list) But I got 18 number of values (Distance values) which should be 19. Because I am finding a distance from origin to all other points stored in a list of X and Y.

```
dist_from_ori = []
i = 0
for i in range(len(X)): 
    
    # Finding a distance between two coordinates (nodes) in first dataframe
    # General formula for this: square root of [(x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2] where x1 and y1 will be constant and second coordinate will vary from x2 to x15
    new_list = np.sqrt((X[i] - origin_x)**2 + (Y[i] - origin_y)**2)
    dist_from_ori.append(new_list)
        
dist_from_ori = [round(num,2) for num in dist_from_ori]       # rounding a obtained values in 'nodal_dist_df1' by 2 decimals
```

The result I got is,

```
dist_from_ori  = [3.61, 5.66, 4.47, 2.24, 4.24, 2.83, 4.12, 3.0, 1.0, 3.61,  5.0, 5.0, 1.41, 4.47, 0.0, 3.16, 4.0, 2.0]
```

Kindly guide me what should I do?

Comment: It seems that you are using numpy. Consider `np.hypot(X, Y).argsort()`.

Comment: To find the index of minimum in dist_from_N1_1 you can use `dist_from_N1_1.index(min(dist_from_N1_1)`.  Also, no need to take square root i.e. you can use distance squared since sqrt is monotonic.

Comment: I have solved the earlier mistake. But I have another issue came up after getting a result. Kindly see my updated question.

Comment: Your result is missing the last point, thus it only has 18 points.  However, when I run your code I get all 19 points.

Comment: Yes, now I also got 19 point. It might had some cache. But all fine now. Thank you

Comment: If your question was related to the missing 19th value, you should close it.